# Is it possible to control the flow of data coming from the Android external keyboard buffer into my app?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, rfid

I am writing an app that will use an externally connected barcode/RFID scanner. The device is a standard HID (Human Interface Device). The device works well; when I scan a barcode or RFID with the reader, the information shows up in an EditText field I have ... no problems at all.

However, this is where it gets tricky for me. Some of the data coming from the RFID tags is "compound" data, meaning there are multiple data points in a single scan. For example:

```
=+03000=W12560712345600=%2800&>0090452359
```

That is from a compound data scan. The delimiter in the data is the equals sign (=) or the ampersand (&). The first bit `=+03000` says that there are three data parts in the scan:

```
=W12560712345600

=%2800

&>0090452359
```

These three data points need to go into three different EditText fields in a form. However, when I scan the tag, the entire string will, obviously, get jammed into a single EditText field. I am trying to populate the entire form from the single scan.

So, is there a way to control the flow of data from the external keyboard buffer into an app? A way I can grab the data before it hits the EditText fields, break it down, then put it where it needs to go? Or, is there another trick that you would recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: You should consider implementing/using TextWatcher (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and filter it out that way. And for clarity, you're not really reading an external keyboard buffer. You're reading data from the scanner and feeding that into an EditText, there is no keyboard interaction here.

Comment: I'll check it out ... thanks.